# I have two table fileA and fleB i want records of similar words data and total row of fileA table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working of to find the percentage of similarity in two files i manage to save the works in tables separately and saved them in two tables

1. fileA
2. fileB

data in FILE-A table

[image: Data in fileA table]

data in FILE-B table

[image: Datain fileB table]

Now i want to write a sql query where i know the numbers of same words rows of both table and total number of rows in fileA table then i want to make a calculation
like

total number of row in file are 7
same words rows of both tables are 4

percentage of similarity = 4/7*100 = 57.14 and display it in browser

i have used this query

```
SELECT fileprints.fileA, fileb.fileB FROM fileprints LEFT JOIN fileB ON fileprints.id=fileB.id WHERE fileprints.fileA=fileb.fileB;
```

it gives me

[image]

**I WANT PERCENTAGE OF SIMILAR WORDS IN BOTH TABLES**

Any expert opinion, suggestions!

Comment: `total number of row in file are 7 same words rows of both tables are 4` 4 what? :/

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari In the question source there’s a line break between “7” and “same”. Maybe this helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. But as per my interpretation, you want percentage of word of fileA matching with fileB.

```
select sum(if(fileb.fileb is null,0,1))/count(*) *100 
from
fileA
left join fileB
on fileA.fileA=fileB.fileB
```

Kindly verify the result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/599b20/2

Assumption: Duplicate word is not present in both table.